# Как сделать лидерборд из 5-ти мест где отображается имя пользователя и кол-во денег

Tags: python, база-данных, telebot, sqlite3

У меня есть таблица там где находятся статистика пользователей

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть код, если пользователь введет Топ в чат, ему выведется самое большое кол-во денег у пользователя.

```
@client.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text(message):
    db = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    sql = db.cursor()

    if message.text == 'Топ':
        max_money_value = sql.execute("SELECT MAX(money) FROM users").fetchone()[0]
        client.send_message(message.chat.id, max_money_value)
```

Comment: в чём заключается ваша проблема? Что вы не можете? Получить эти данные? Не знаете как форматировать их в виде "топа"?

Comment: Хочу лидерборд сделать, но не знаю как

Comment: Смотрите, вы получаете как я вижу данные из базы данных. Вам по сути их осталось лишь отправить пользователю, что вам мешает это сделать?

Comment: Получаю только максимальное значение из столбца money

Comment: верно, вы ведь так составили запрос. Если вас это интересует, то стоит перефразировать вопрос и тогда я на него отвечу

Comment: и как же⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀